# Assign auto_ptr to weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

I am still exploring C++ 11. So I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. But I just can't figure out the problem.

I have following Code:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const PlayerEventListener* eventListener)
{
   weak_ptr<PlayerEventListener> _listener;
   std::auto_ptr<PlayerEventListener> autoPtr;
   autoPtr.reset(const_cast<PlayerEventListener*> (eventListener));
   // I get error for this line
   _listener = autoPtr;
}
```

I get following error: **No viable overloaded '='**

But following code compiles fine:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const PlayerEventListener* eventListener)
{
   weak_ptr<PlayerEventListener> _listener;
   std::shared_ptr<PlayerEventListener> sharedPtr;
   sharedPtr.reset(const_cast<PlayerEventListener*> (eventListener));
   // I get error for this line
   _listener = sharedPtr;
}
```

Can somebody explain why I cannot convert a auto pointer to weak pointer?

Comment: `auto_ptr` doesn't have a reference counter that a `weak_ptr` would be observing

Comment: An `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11 and is basically a `std::unique_ptr`, you can't copy a unique_ptr.

Comment: "I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong" - Yes, you are using `auto_ptr`

Comment: You should note `auto_ptr` is deprecated. Also there's no way to create any higher level smart pointer from a `weak_ptr`. They're secondary citizens depending on others, not vice versa.

Comment: This constructor can not be correctly written without knowing if `eventListener` was heap allocated or not, and if so, if something else currently maintaining ownership of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) is an object that holds a safe reference to an object actually held by `shared_ptr`, not `auto_ptr`. Therefore, there is no any  overloaded `operator=` that could provide assigning `auto_ptr` to `weak_ptr` in the implementation of `weak_ptr`. It can be verified by compiling [this example code](http://cpp.sh/4s7d) and looking at the error

```
In constructor 'MyClass::MyClass(const PlayerEventListener*)':
21:14: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::weak_ptr<PlayerEventListener>' and 'std::auto_ptr<PlayerEventListener>')
```

---

*Just to remember:* According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/ :

> This class template (`auto_ptr`) is deprecated as of C++11. `unique_ptr` is a new
>   facility with a similar functionality, but with improved security (no
>   fake copy assignments), added features (deleters) and support for
>   arrays. See [`unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) for additional information.

Comment: That `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated, doesn't answer the question though!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Updated answer.